# ¿como agrego una consulta de LinQ a una lista? realizado desde un web services

Tags: c#, webservice, linq

Buen día a todos, tengo un pequeño inconveniente, soy nuevo en ésto de `LinQ` y **Web Services**, actualmente tengo un problema que no hallo como solucionarlo, el siguiente es que quiero agregar mi consulta hecha con `LinQ`

```
var db = new db_ss_atcEntities();

var query = (from pro in db.proveedores where pro.pro_codigosap == res.LIFNR select pro).ToList();
```

he intento almacenarla en una nueva lista:

```
proveedores prove = new proveedores();
```

si intento agregarlo en un `forEach`

```
foreach ( var i in query )
{
 proveedores a = new proveedores();
 a.Add(i);
}
```

me dice que **"proveedores"** no contiene una referencia para `Add`, entonces no se si tengo que: ¿crear algún método o una clase? estoy trabajando en un método `POST()`.

Comment: Si "i" ya es de tipo "proveedores" por qué intentas crear un nuevo objeto ? asumo que query te devuelve una lista de objetos de tipo "proveedores", "i" deberia ser un objeto de tipo proveedores

Comment: Quita esta linea del **Foreach**  `proveedores a = new proveedores();` ya que si la pones hay , en cada iteracion del foreachs la va a limpiar. y el objeto **"a"** que es de tipo **proveedores** debe ser asi `List<proveedores> a = new List<proveedores>();` para que puedas hacer un add

Comment: Ahora mi pregunta es si ya tienes una lista de proveedores para que la vuelves a pasar a un objeto de tipo proveedores ? , seria mejor declarar la variable query de tipo proveedores así `List<proveedores> query = (from pro in db.proveedores ....`

Comment: Podrias explicar mejor que es lo que queres hacer? a donde es que queres llegar? porque tu linq ya te devuelve una lista de proveedores.. y ahora que queres hacer?

Comment: Saludos hermano, espero que este par de enlaces te sean de utilidad para tu entrenamiento en Linq: https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/ y https://www.tutorialspoint.com/entity_framework/index.htm

Comment: @fredyfx gracias hermanazo!!

Comment: con cariño hermano, todos empezamos en algún lado, esta comunidad es colaboración en su más alta expresión. A elevar ese cosmos y a darle con todo el power 2.0!!! Buena suerte :D

Answer (score 0):

Bueno según lo que veo en tu código tienes varios errores:

**Primero**: Cuando haces esto

```
proveedores prove = new proveedores();
```

No estas creando una lista estas creando un objeto para que sea una lista debes agregar `List<>` así:

```
List<proveedores> prove = new List<proveedores>();
```

**Segundo**: y muy importante... ya tienes una variable la cual recibe una lista de tu consulta `LinQ` la cual es **query** que es de tipo **`var`** seria mejor que la declararas `List<proveedores>` **query**.

**Tercero**: si deseas hacerlo como tienes declarado debes de sacar la declaración del objeto o variable "a la cual le debes agregar `List<>`, esta: `proveedores prove = new proveedores();` del `foreach` ya que al momento de recorrer los ítem que tenga **query** esta se va inicializar nuevamente.

Tu codigo deberia de verse asi:

```
var db = new db_ss_atcEntities();

List<proveedores> query= (from pro in db.proveedores 
    where pro.pro_codigosap == res.LIFNR select pro).ToList();
```

Comment: no es necesario que realice esos pasos, esta haciendo un foreach innecesario, ya que la variable query contiene la lista de proveedores

Comment: "que es de tipo var seria mejor que la declararas List<proveedores> query o la puedes dejar de tipo var ya que esta puede contener cualquier tipo." NO, VAR no contiene cualquier cosa. Var es sintactic sugar donde el compilador va a inferir el tipo de dato en tiempo de desarrollo y lo va a agregar al momento de compilar. No compila var, compila el tipo que corresponde.

Answer (score 0):

La clase `proveedores` no es una lista, sino una simple instancia, la lista ya la estas obteniendo cuando usas `ToList()` en el linq

quizas no lo observas pero usa

```
 List<proveedores> query = (from pro in db.proveedores where pro.pro_codigosap == res.LIFNR select pro).ToList();
```

Nota: imagine la clase se llama `proveedores` sino es asi deberias poner la correcta que defines en el dbcontext

Es mas podrias hacerlo mas simple

```
List<proveedores> query = db.proveedores.Where(pro=> pro.pro_codigosap == res.LIFNR).ToList();
```